# Java rest service and web application not running on same project

Tags: tomcat, jersey, java

I have one Java dynamic web project, in this project I have rest service and web application both.

My web application all data is on "WebContent" folder.

My index.html page is located on "WebContent" folder.

My web.xml code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>TestingMerge</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestingMerge</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestingMerge</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My service code

```
package TestingMerge.aitc.io;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/TM")
public class TestingMerge_Service {
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Path("/Register")
    public Response Register(String json) {
        JSONObject returnJson = new JSONObject();

        try {
            JSONObject innerJsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
            User_Objects userObj = new User_Objects();
            String email = innerJsonObj.getString("email");
            String phone = innerJsonObj.getString("phone");

            JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
            returnJson.put("success", true);
            returnJson.put("data", jsonData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JSONObject errorJson = new JSONObject();
            errorJson.put("success", false);
            return Response.ok(errorJson.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
        }

        return Response.ok(returnJson.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
    }
}
```

Currently when i run this project then hit `http://localhost:8080/TestingMerge/` URL on my browser it show me blank page.
But i am able to run my rest service using the below URL

```
http://localhost:8080/TestingMerge/TM/Register
```

If i removed the below code from web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>TestingMerge</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>TestingMerge</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then run this project then hit `http://localhost:8080/TestingMerge/` URL on my browser my application is running successfully.
But my rest service not call using `http://localhost:8080/TestingMerge/TM/Register` URL.

I am using Java and Tomcat 8.

Comment: I think your `/*` servlet mapping overrides the Tomcat's default servlet (which is used to serve JSP pages and static files, such as HTML or images). I would change the TestingMerge servlet mapping to `/TM/*`.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I just updated by service code on my post. Please check it again, May be this help to find any issue.

Comment: I can be wrong, but I would still say, the problem is in the `/*` mapping - you should map the Jersey service container to e.g. `/rest/*` and then use `http://localhost:8080/TestingMerge/rest/TM/Register` to call it. This way the default servlet won't be overriden, and will serve the static files (and JSPs).

Comment: @JozefChocholacek If I change my /* to /TM/* my application is running using "http://localhost:8080/TestingMerge/" successfully. But my service URL is become from "http://localhost:8080/TestingMerge/TM/Register" to "http://localhost:8080/TestingMerge/TM/TM/Register". Can I call my service with "http://localhost:8080/TestingMerge/TM/Register" URL?

Comment: Btw. perhaps would be useful to add `jersey` tag to your question.